# Eclipse Mars crashes when saving large Java enum file with StackOverflowError

Tags: eclipse

I'm simply saving a Java file with a large enum (total 1474 lines in file which is enum constants including some line wraps and a bit of other code) and each time Eclipse Mars crashes with the following log. Turns out the file is actually saved once I restart eclipse. Any ideas please? Thanks!

```
!MESSAGE Save Failed
!STACK 0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.TokenManager.get(TokenManager.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.linewrap.WrapExecutor.getWrapIndent(WrapExecutor.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.linewrap.WrapExecutor$LineAnalyzer.token(WrapExecutor.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.TokenTraverser.traverse(TokenTraverser.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.TokenManager.traverse(TokenManager.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.linewrap.WrapExecutor$LineAnalyzer.analyzeLine(WrapExecutor.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.linewrap.WrapExecutor.findWraps(WrapExecutor.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.linewrap.WrapExecutor.findWrapsCached(WrapExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.linewrap.WrapExecutor.findWraps(WrapExecutor.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.linewrap.WrapExecutor.findWrapsCached(WrapExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.linewrap.WrapExecutor.findWraps(WrapExecutor.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.linewrap.WrapExecutor.findWrapsCached(WrapExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.linewrap.WrapExecutor.findWraps(WrapExecutor.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.linewrap.WrapExecutor.findWrapsCached(WrapExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.linewrap.WrapExecutor.findWraps(WrapExecutor.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.linewrap.WrapExecutor.findWrapsCached(WrapExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.linewrap.WrapExecutor.findWraps(WrapExecutor.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.linewrap.WrapExecutor.findWrapsCached(WrapExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.linewrap.WrapExecutor.findWraps(WrapExecutor.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.linewrap.WrapExecutor.findWrapsCached(WrapExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.linewrap.WrapExecutor.findWraps(WrapExecutor.java:449)
```

.....

Comment: You could always post the enum, but if the enum successfully compiles, then this sounds like a bug in Eclipse and should be filed at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/ . Since the bug appears to be with the formatter, you can try turning off auto formatting on save in Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions.

Answer (score 1):

I have filed this as a bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=476960

The resolution can be tracked in the eclipse tracker

It should be fixed in 4.5.1 (you can download the latest release candidate from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/).

Or you can use one of these workarounds:

1. Set line wrapping policy for Method declarations -> Declaration to "Do not wrap".
2. Temporarily change indentation policy to spaces only, make sure both indentation size and tab size are the same, then switch back to tabs only.